# Have conditional formatting macro skip blanks in Excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, vba

I have using the Recorder Macro the following:

```
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="=0", Formula2:="=19.5"
  Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
  With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Bold = False
        .Italic = True
        .ColorIndex = 4

    End With
  Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = True

    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="=19.6", Formula2:="=34.4"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
  With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Bold = False
        .Italic = True
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.499984740745262
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

Then I use a macro to cut all the conditions and leave only the formatting. However, no matter what I did, Isblank, adding another conditional formatting conditions to only run on non blanks, after the conditional formatting macro, the formatting is green (which turns any 0-19.5 green, but there was nothing in the cell).

Is there a way to add a skip line to this macro? If it is blank I want it to move to the next cell. I don't have set ranges so that's why it's all on selection.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through each cell in the selection and only apply the format if the cell is not blank.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim cel As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next

For Each cel In Selection
    If cel <> "" Then

    cel.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="=0", Formula2:="=19.5"
  cel.FormatConditions(cel.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
  With cel.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Bold = False
        .Italic = True
        .ColorIndex = 4

    End With
  cel.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = True

    cel.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="=19.6", Formula2:="=34.4"
    cel.FormatConditions(cel.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
  With cel.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Bold = False
        .Italic = True
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.499984740745262
    End With
    cel.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

With cel
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
cel.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

End If

Next cel
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hm, I thought this might work but when I use find replace the color format of green to **, it turns blank cells into ** with green formatting. Also after I use my macro to cut formatting when I type numbers in that cell, it is green. I think my conditional formatting macro (which I can't post here) keeps the formatting while removing conditions in order, and the "default" result is the green. If I add a condition to format the cell blank font if the cell is blank, would that help?

Comment: I've read your comment five times. I still have no idea what you mean. The macro I posted performs the formatting actions you had in your macro. It just does not apply it to empty cells. That was the question and this is the answer. If you have another problem, please ask a new question.

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear. Step 1: Apply the current above macro. Step 2: Apply my cut conditions and leave only formatting macro. Step 3: use find and replace all the low sample green formatting to **. In this situation, all blank cells now contain a ** instead of being blank, which is my problem. The find replace thinks there is green formatting in blank cells (which was a result of the 1st macro).

Comment: Did you run a macro on your file that set the green CF in blank cells, and ***then*** you applied the macro I supplied? If so, the blank cells will contain the CF that was applied with the first macro. You need to delete the CF from these cells. You could  use the Ribbon command to remove ALL CF from the whole sheet and start over with the correct macro.

Comment: No, I just used your macro then my 2nd macro(which cuts the conditional formatting). While the blanks are avoided when the "conditions are being met" once the conditions are "cut" the blank cells have green formatting.

Comment: I don't know what your second macro does and what exactly the problem is. Let's recap: You posted a macro and wanted this macro to skip blank cells. I posted a modification of your macro that skips blank cells. Everything you commented after that is virtually indecipherable. If you want more targeted help, please post a sample file. On the other hand: Your question as posted has been answered. If you need help with a different aspect, accept this answer and start a new question, where you post ALL the code you use and also post a sample file. Nobody wants to guess what your color codes are.

Answer (score 0):

If the formatting is all that you want, then use the macro that you have recorded here and simply copy the code that causes the formatting.

```
 With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Bold = False
        .Italic = True
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.499984740745262
 End With
```

This block of code seems to have some of the formatting that you might want.

Also, because you are working with a selection instead of each cell individually, checking for a blank cell would be more difficult. As far as I know, you can't do it because you are treating the selection as a whole range. A cell is a range as well. Someone correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I need to apply the formatting onto a different set of data but without the conditions, so I can't just use the macro to format data (since it wouldn't be correct). I could use a formula but my data is not the same size or in the same place every single time...

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue with conditional formatting myself, with cells that are either blank or have a string value, where I wished to ignore the former.

I found that conditional formatting functions do not work correctly with ADDRESS(), but that I could write user-defined functions to use with =AND(), which got around the issue.

```
Public Function CellContent() As Variant

  On Error Resume Next

  CellContent = Application.Caller.value

End Function

Public Function Cell_HasContent() As Boolean

  On Error Resume Next

  If Application.Caller.value = "" Then
    Cell_HasContent = False
  Else
    Cell_HasContent = True
  End If

End Function
```

The Resume Next statements are critical. If you're trying to check that any non-blanks have a value of say, 2, you can now check this with:

```
Formula1:="=AND(CellContent()=2,CellHasContent())"
```